# static bool defined in header works for one file only, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new in Objective-C

I try to integrate `asl_log`. For some reason static bool always has `NO` value in other files.

I created header `MyLogger.h` with content:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <asl.h>

static bool gLoggingEnabled = NO;

#define __AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(LEVEL, NAME) \
static inline void NAME(NSString *format, ...)\
{ \
  if (!gLoggingEnabled) return; \
  va_list arg_list; \
  va_start(arg_list, format); \
  NSString *formattedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:arg_list]; \
  asl_add_log_file(NULL, STDERR_FILENO); \
  asl_log(NULL, NULL, (LEVEL), "Prog_ASL:  %s", [formattedString UTF8String]); \
  va_end(arg_list); \
}    

__AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION(ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG, AFLogDebug)



#undef __AF_MAKE_LOG_FUNCTION
```

You can see that I use `static bool gLoggingEnabled` as switch.

From my main project file I do:

```
#import "AFLogger.h"

// ...

gLoggingEnabled = YES;

if (gLoggingEnabled) {
    asl_add_log_file(NULL, STDERR_FILENO);
    //set log level
    asl_set_filter(NULL, ASL_FILTER_MASK_UPTO(ASL_LEVEL_DEBUG));
} else {
    asl_remove_log_file(NULL, STDERR_FILENO);
}  

AFLogDebug(@"flag is %@", gLoggingEnabled ? @"Yes" : @"No");
 // -> flag is Yes
```

However it works only in one file.

I have other `.m` file:

```
 #import "AFLogger.h"

 //...
 NSLog(@"flag is %@", gLoggingEnabled ? @"Yes" : @"No");
 // -> flag is No

 // AFLogDebug prints nothing
```

**Why `static bool gLoggingEnabled` has `No` value in other files**

How to fix it?

**[EDIT]**

I want to avoid to use `extern`

Answer (score 2):

It's `static` so each .m file that you import `MyLogger.h` into gets its own copy of the `gLoggingEnabled` variable.

If you want a single, app-wide variable, then you need to change 2 things.

In `MyLogger.h` you need to change `static` to `extern`:

```
extern bool gLoggingEnabled;
```

In `MyLogger.m` you need to add:

```
bool gLoggingEnabled = NO;
```

That declaration pairs with the `extern`. This is the app-wide global variable.

Then in any file, you can change its value:

```
gLoggingEnabled = YES; // or NO as needed
```

That last line will change the value for the entire app (any file that includes `MyLogger.h`).

Comment: so why Mixpanel use `static`? https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/blob/master/Mixpanel/MPLogger.h

Comment: Using `static` allows each file (.m) to turn logging on or off for itself without affecting what other files choose to do.

Comment: Also I don't have `.m` file and MixPanel call `MPLogError` from 20-30 files and I have no clue why they don't use `extern`

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a definition of the variable. What you want is a declaration. Not only that, the `static` modifier limits its visibility to the compilation unit it is defined in. Essentially, every `.c` or `.m` file has its own copy of `gLoggingEnabled` which only it can see.

What you need to do is create a non static file scope variable in in one `.c` or `.m` file

```
bool gLoggingEnabled = false; // Note, using C11 bool definitions
```

Then you add an external declaration in the header. This is like a promise to the compiler that you may not have defined the storage for the variable in the current compilation unit, but it will be done at link time.

```
extern bool gLoggingEnabled;
```